# Algorithm to determine Facebook user IDs?

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing a PHP script to crawl the Facebook API and record all the User IDs.

For example:

- https://graph.facebook.com/4 (Mark Zuckerberg)
- https://graph.facebook.com/9 (not a valid User ID; represents another Facebook object type)

My first thought was to start from #4 and increment by 1 every time.  The problem with this plan is that there's hugs gaps in the user IDs.  Sometimes the API will return false for every number in a series of 100,000. And this just wastes time and cycles for my script running through all these falses.

Does anyone know of a better way to determine every valid Facebook user ID?

Comment: I wouldn't have your script in mind, but the facebook server. It is a waste of time for them as well. Also, I'm pretty sure such crawling is against the ToS of the API.

Comment: What's the end-goal of this script? I suspect that there must be an easier way to achieve your goal, assuming that such result is not a violation of the terms of service of the API.

Comment: I think it's a secret. The IDs are probably generated by a formula. Even though you have figured out the formula, you still do't have the parameters to plug into the formula. If you're gonna crawl users, what I suggest is to use BFS/DFS to search a user's friends. I'm not sure whether it's against the term of use though.

Comment: @Femaref - I don't see any thing in the Facebook Platform Policies that doesn't allow what I'm doing.  But I agree with your point, that's why I'm trying to improve the algorithm ;)

Comment: @DavidThomas - It's a secret :)  But it does comply with all the TOS that I've seen.

Comment: "Algorithm" is too big word here.

Comment: It doesn't comply with the main Facebook TOS, so you didn't look all that hard...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is in violation of Facebooks [Terms of Service](https://www.facebook.com/terms.php) 3.2:

> You will not collect users' content or information, or otherwise
>   access Facebook, using automated means (such as harvesting bots,
>   robots, spiders, or scrapers) without our permission.

You should also read this guys post about how he got [sued by Facebook](http://petewarden.typepad.com/searchbrowser/2010/04/how-i-got-sued-by-facebook.html) for doing something very similar.

One of the reason there are gaps  is that originally id's were allocated in 100k groups per school.  So you will see old Facebook accounts from the same old with similar looking ids.  Also, Facebook doesn't provide any other api's or information about getting a list of all of their id's.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know of a better way to determine every valid Facebook user ID?

It's a pointless endeavor. Facebook hands out IDs from the same numeric space to everything - any page on the Internet with a like button, any Facebook page, photos, albums, groups, apps, checkins, comments, messages, posts, videos, etc. For every one valid ID there may be hundreds of thousands of non-user IDs in between.

It'd take you years to crawl, but Facebook would block you well before that.